# Difference of two definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

$F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$
$$F\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x^2+ax+5\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Find $a$ so that $$\int _0^2\left(F\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int _{-2}^0\left(F\left(x\right)\right)dx=2$$

I don't think I need to actually integrate my function, since it would be rather troublesome to do so. My answer key says that $$\int _0^2\left(F\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int _{-2}^0\left(F\left(x\right)\right)dx=\int _0^2\left(\frac{\left(x^2+ax+5-x^2+ax-5\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)dx=\\2a\int _0^2\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$
but I can't figure out why. Surely, this is easy to integrate and get a value for $a$, but how do I get here?

Comment: Do the terms "odd function" and "even function" ring a bell?

Comment: Well, odd function is when $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and even function is when $f(x)=f(-x)$

Comment: The difference are just the odd parts of $F(x)$ which may be integrated triviallly

Comment: Right. And every function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ has a unique decomposition as the sum of an even and an odd function. If $g$ is even, what is $\int_0^c g(x)\,dx - \int_{-c}^0 g(x)\,dx$?

Comment: I edited a small hint into your question ;)

Comment: But why does $\int _{-2}^0F\left(x\right)=\int _0^2\left(F\left(-x\right)\right)dx$ ?

Comment: Only the even part of F !

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, using the theory of calculus I'd get $G(c)-G(0)-G(0)+G(-c)$ where $G'(x)=g(x)$ so if the function is even, then $G(c)=G(-c)$ and my difference would be $2G(c)-2G(0)$, so $2(G(c)-G(0))$ which would be $2\int _0^c\left(g\left(x\right)\right)dx$

Comment: But my $F(x)$ isn't even! :(

Comment: If $g$ is even, its primitives are of the form "constant + odd function". But one can see that $\int_0^c g(x)\,dx = \int_{-c}^0 g(x)\,dx$ for even $g$ by the symmetry. So for the difference $\int_0^2 F(x)\,dx - \int_{-2}^0 F(x)\,dx$, only the odd part of $F$ matters.

Comment: So if I were to separate my function $F(x)=e(x)-o(x)$ where $e(x)$ is even and $o(x)$ is odd, then the difference $\int _0^c\left(F\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int _{-c}^0\left(F\left(x\right)\right)dx$ would be equal to $2\int _0^c\left(o\left(x\right)\right)dx$?

Comment: Correct! exactly what is already stated in your question for this particular problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

write $$F(x)=\dfrac{x^2+5}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\dfrac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=f(x)+g(x) $$
and note that: $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $g(-x)=-g(x)$

---

For the integral of the even part you have:
$$
\int_{-2}^0f(x)dx=\int_{-2}^0f(-x)dx=-\int_0^{-2}f(-x)dx=
$$
and substituting $-x=t$ this last become $\int_0^{2}f(t)dt$, and renaming $t=x$ you find
 $\int_0^{2}f(x)dx-\int_{-2}^0f(x)dx=0$

And you can do similar for the odd part.

Comment: But what do I get when I try to write $\int _0^c\left(g\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int _{-c}^0\left(g\left(x\right)\right)dx$ for an odd function? It would just be $G(c)-G(0)-G(0)+G(-c)$ and $G(-c)=-G(c)$ hence $\int _0^c\left(g\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int _{-c}^0\left(g\left(x\right)\right)dx=-2G(0)$ which is 0?

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope it's useful.